# jQuery Datepicker not showing in WordPress environment

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I have a code that works perfectly well standalone as a fiddle but fails to work once I import the code into my WordPress environment. Basically I am trying to restrict the selectable dates based on a date range array.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rLnTQ/658/

Any Reason why this would not work when I import into my WordPress pages? I believe it may be something to do with the reference to the "beforeShowDay: disabledays" ..

Here is my code anyway:

```
var unavailableDates = ["29-6-2013"];

function disabledays(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0) 
    {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"]
    } 
    else 
    {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [true, "", ""];
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#bookingDate').datepicker({
                                changeMonth:true, 
                                changeYear:true, 
                                dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",  
                                minDate:"+2d", 
                                constrainInput: true,
                                beforeShowDay: disabledays
                            });
});
```

Comment: TypeError: $ is undefined  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0) {

Comment: What exactly is the problem? doesn't the date picker show up at all? Can you post a link to your site or create a failing example?

Comment: What is the error?? it may have jQuery conflict issue, have you got the chance to see in chrome if there is any error being shown.

Comment: The date picker doesn't show up at all.. I believe I may need to rename the $ inside disabledays to something else.. ??

Comment: you are also missing a `;` in your `if`-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working fine, seems like you had `$ alias conflict`, there are couple of solutions for it

1) `jQuery.inArray` instead of `$.inArray`

2) Another workaround that i prefer is to use noConflict function given by jQuery to tackle this issue, you can read more here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

Also you can try this code (neat version of your code :) ),

```
var unavailableDates = ["6-29-2013","6-27-2013","7-2-2013"];

function disabledays(date) {
var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();    

    for (i = 0; i < unavailableDates.length; i++) {
        if(jQuery.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,unavailableDates) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
            return [false];
        }
        return [true];
    }
 }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#bookingDate').datepicker({
                                    changeMonth:true, 
                                    changeYear:true, 
                                    dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",  
                                    minDate:"+2d", 
                                    constrainInput: true,
                                    beforeShowDay: disabledays
                                });
    });
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rLnTQ/659/

Comment: It is being called. I placed it as follows:

dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
alert('disabledays called'); 
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0)

Comment: i have update my answer code as per your requirement above, try that out. it is working perfect in fiddle

Comment: My code also works in jsfiddle as demonstrated above... It's when I import into WordPress environment that the issue arises.. But let me try your code anyway.. pretty sure I will get the same error..

Comment: yup.. exactly the same error.. 

if($.inArray((m+1)

The "$" is undefined... somehow need to map this..

Comment: i would suggest bro that you check all the comments properly on your question next time, i commented this an hour ago that it seems to have jQuery conflict issue..

Comment: I did check all the comments and you didn't mention anything about changing the $ to jQuery.. Anyway, thanks for the help. It is solved now. If you think my question was clear please mark likewise.